# Increasing event sequence question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

In an exercise, if $ \{ X_n \} $ is a random variable sequence and $X$ another random variable, I am requested to show that the event sequence $\{T_n\}$ is increasing, where:

$$
T_m = \{ |X_n-X| < ε \quad \forall \; n \geq m \} \quad , m \in \mathbb{N}
$$
for some $ε>0$.

However I think that it is decreasing, because
$$
T_m = \{ |X_n-X| < ε \quad \forall \; n \geq m \} \supset 
\{ |X_n-X| < ε \quad \forall \; n \geq m+1 \} = T_{m+1}
$$

Where is the mistake?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If something happens for all $n \geq m$ in particular it happens for all $n \geq m+1$, so the inclusion is the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inclusion is actually wrong.

Let $\omega\in T_m$. Then, by definition:  $$|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|<\varepsilon \quad \forall n\ge m.$$
This holds for all $n\ge m$, then holds in particular for all $n\ge m+1$ and hence
$$\omega\in T_{m+1},$$ so you have
$$T_m \subseteq T_{m+1}$$

You got confused in the inclusion: if $\omega\in T_{m+1}$ than you don't know anything about $n=m$.

Comment: First, $\omega \in T_{m} \cap \omega \in  T_{m+1} $  is written wrong, it has no meaning. Then, to check if $T_m \subseteq T_{m+1}$ you have to see if, for all $\omega\in T_m$,  holds $\omega\in T_{m+1}$. I did this, and it's true, hence $T_m \subseteq T_{m+1}$

Comment: Yeah I totally see it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important thing here is to realize the condition $\textbf{ for all } n \geq m$, which can be a very small ('strict') event, e.g. 'all tosses=Heads after $m^{th}$ toss', so if you define an indicator function for the event:
$$
I_{T_{m}} = \mathbf{1}_{|X_{n \geq m}-X| < \varepsilon}
$$
This event will be all $1s$ for $n \geq m$. On the other hand for $m+1, I_{T_{m+1}}$ includes both $I_{T_{m}} = \{0,1\}$, i.e. both the event and its compliment, so it's a larger (less strict) event, hence $I_{T_{m}}  \subset  I_{T_{m+1}} $ and, hence $ T_{m} \subset T_{m+1}$